# Configure SASS Load Path in Nuxt 3

Tags: sass, vite, nuxtjs3

I have my SCSS partials in my Nuxt 3 project's `assets/css` directory (e.g. `assets/css/_cards.scss`). I can import them in my components using the full path (`@use '~/assets/css/cards';`), but I'm having trouble getting the [load path](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#load-paths) working so that I can import like `@use 'cards';`

From what I've seen, the Nuxt config should look like this to enable that, but this and similar variations are not working for me.

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    vite: {
        css: {
            preprocessorOptions: {
                scss: {
                    loadPaths: ['@/assets/css'],
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct key to use is `includePaths` which is documented [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api/interfaces/LegacyFileOptions#includePaths). I tried this key before, but the reason it did not work was that I used `@/assets/css` for the path. The `@` alias does not work in this option, so I needed to use `./assets/css` for the path. Here is the corrected config:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    vite: {
        css: {
            preprocessorOptions: {
                scss: {
                    includePaths: ['./assets/css'],
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not working for me either. However, my use case is that I wanted some global styles imported, as opposed to every component on its own.

What worked for me was to use `css` property directly inside `defineNuxtConfig` object.

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ["@/assets/css/_variables.scss"]
});
```

Comment: This answer is unrelated to my question. My question is about how to shorten CSS imports, not how to set global CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in vite build (a bit out):

```
css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
                "load-path": './node_modules'
            },
        },
    },
```